# c# - UWP - UnauthorizedAccessException on file included in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm writing a UWP app in Visual Studio 2015 community and getting the following exception when I run the build and the app tries to open a file that I added to the project using **Project | Add New Item** from VS.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access to the path 'C:\Users\garre\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\projectdates.xml' is denied.
  Source=ProjectManager
  StackTrace:
       at ProjectManager.DataController.<CheckDates>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at ProjectManager.MainPage.<<projectsPivot_Click>b__21_0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at ProjectManager.MainPage.<projectsPivot_Click>d__21.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

and here's the code snippet that is trying to access the file:

```
XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create(
    File.Open("projectdates.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
);
```

lastly, here's a screenshot of my solution tree:

[image: VS Solution Explorer]

I've already checked that the file exists (Copy setting is "Copy if newer" in properties view of VS) and that the permissions are such that my user account can access it (read/write/execute). I've even trying opening VS with admin rights and to no prevail.

**Edit:**
Here are the properties for the XML prior to receiving the exception:

[image: projectdates.xml properties]

**Edit 2:**
Alright, I've tried using the `StorageFile` method of accessing the file and now I'm getting this new exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at ProjectManager.DataController.<GetData>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at ProjectManager.MainPage.<<projectsPivot_Load>b__21_0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at ProjectManager.MainPage.<projectsPivot_Load>d__21.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: If you are accessing the file like that, drop it in the bin/debug folder and not in the main application directory.

Comment: @OmarZaarour, as I mentioned, I have the option "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Copy if newer" in the properties for the file (although maybe I wasn't 100% clear about it). This will effectively place the file in the bin/debug folder when building the project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exception you are seeing is likely due to the sandboxing in Windows Universal Apps. However, the documentation for [File.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s67691sb(v=vs.110).aspx) does not mention it.

Typically in Windows Runtime apps, you have to use [StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) instead of FileStream:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

async public Task ReadXmlFile()
{
    // Use ONE of the following lines to get the file:
    var sf = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.TryGetItemAsync("projectdates.xml") as StorageFile;
    var sf = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///projectdates.xml"));

    var stream = await sf.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create(stream);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Correct, you can't just arbitrarily open a file, you need to use the RuntimeBroker to handle it, and the only mechanism that can talk to RuntimeBroker is the StorageFile API. There's several examples of working with XML files in the [XmlDocument sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument) and examples on [more complex file handling](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess) in Microsoft's samples github.

Comment: The bit about using a `StorageFile` was very helpful in solving my issue! I actually ended up using `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to store and access the files, rather than have them included in the project.

Comment: What does the app developer do then if they want to write a utility such as maybe making a piegraph of hard disk usage program similar to Disktective in UWP?

Answer (score 1):

Change your file’s Build Action to Content.

For XML with LINQ:

```
var path =  Path.Combine(
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, 
            "projectdates.xml");
XDocument data = XDocument.Load(path);
```

[Also relevant](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a malformed path...does "c:...\documents" really exist? if not, try getting the path like so:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\visual studio 2015\Projects\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\projectdates.xml"
```

Comment: You mention using Environment.GetFolderPath, but that hasn't been projected to WinRT for UWP apps (it's not part of the .NET Core API set, it's part of the bigger Framework Client profile). It's only available to classic desktop c# apps and Windows phone 8.1 apps. Neither is Environment.SpecialFolder.